How to mock a function inside a react component with Jest?
I have a component, with the following function inside of it:
const RolloutPage = () => {

    const getServiceHistory = async (serviceName, account) => {
        return await fetch() ...
    };

    return <Page> ...
}
export default withRouter(RolloutPage);

How can i mock the inside function? I have tried:
jest.spyOn(<RolloutPage/>, 'getServiceHistory').mockImplementation(() =>
        Promise.resolve({
            json: () => Promise.resolve({ serviceTimelineDataMock }),
        })
    );
    render(<MemoryRouter>
            <RolloutPage/>
           </MemoryRouter>)

But it gives me the following error:

Cannot spy the getServiceHistory property because it is not a function; undefined given instead

I have tried some of the other answers here in SO, but none of them worked.

It's not a property of the component. You don't mock it, it's an internal implementation detail.

I'm not sure that I get it, jon. I can't mock this function? I made it work by mocking the fetch function inside of it. But I wish I could mock getServiceHistory instead.

Can't and shouldn't. It only exists inside the function invocation. I wouldn't mock fetch either for that matter, same as axios here.

You can't mock it because getServiceHistory function is private. It defines in the component function scope. You can't access it outside of the component. For example, in the test file. So neither jest.mock() nor jest.spyOn() will work.
Besides, as @jonrsharpe said, You should avoid mocking implementation details so refactors of your components (changes to implementation but not functionality) don't break your tests and slow you and your team down.
We should use black-box strategy to test RolloutPage component. In other words, testing components from the user's perspective. Users do not care about the implementation details of a component, only its functionality.
For example, the test steps are:

Render the component
Assert what does the component render
Fire an event on an React element
Assert what does the component render

Take a look this example

We recommend using the Mock Service Worker (MSW) library to declaratively mock API communication in your tests instead of stubbing window.fetch, or relying on third-party adapters.

